# How to group custom App parts in a single group/category?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365, grouping

I have **many app parts** which i want to be **under single group or category**. So, when i will go in the "Edit mode" of the page, I will see my apps in a separate category. Please refer the below picture:

[image]

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

**For new web parts:**

1. Go to site>Gear icon>Site Settings> (Web Designer Galleries) Web parts>Upload new file>Upload the file>the following form appears:
   [image]
2. Under the Group tab choose specify your own value and enter the name of your custom folder.
3. Save and close.
4. If you go now to Home>Edit page>Insert web part   you can see the folder and the web part inside it:
   [image]

**For existing web parts:**

1. Go to the Site Settings>(Web Designer Galleries) Web parts>Find the web part you want to move to your folder and click on Edit properties:
   [image]

   2. The following edit form appears:
      [image]
   3. Under the Group tab enter the name of your folder. If the folder does not exist, it will be created.